# Adding a count variable as a suffix in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a new view in SQL Server 2008 R2.
Given is a col called "ADRESS", based on which I want to create a col called "CompanyID".
I want to add a suffix, which counts +1 for each row in a group of adresses, ideally starting from ".002".
The output should look like this:

| ADRESS | CompanyID |
| --- | --- |
| 100000 | 100000.002 |
| 100000 | 100000.003 |
| 100000 | 100000.004 |
| 200000 | 100000.002 |
| 200000 | 100000.003 |
| 300000 | 100000.002 |

My idea was to declare a count variable:

```
DECLARE @count AS 
SET @count = '002'
```

And then use a while loop:

```
WHILE ()
BEGIN 
  SELECT ADRESS + '.' + @count AS CompanyID
  SET @count = @count +1 
END
```

Problem is, I don't have a idea what to loop through and also, which data type allows 3 digits without removing the first two zeros. I'm new to SQL so i would appreciate a short explanation.

Comment: Can't you just use a `ROW_NUMBER` for this?

Comment: That was a great idea, thank!
Maybe this helps someone in the future:
`RIGHT('000'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ADRESS]) +1 AS VARCHAR(3)),3) AS SUFFIX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

- Use ROW_NUMBER() to get your ordered numbers
- +1 to start from 2
- Cast to varchar
- Add 000 in front
- Cut to last 3 characters - RIGHT()
- Add Address and '.' in front

---

```
 SELECT ADRESS 
, CAST(ADRESS AS VARCHAR(10)) 
  + '.' 
  + RIGHT('000' + CAST(1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ADRESS ORDER BY ADRESS) AS VARCHAR(3)),3) AS CompanyId
FROM Table1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/18XixnLy)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
SELECT Address, CAST(Address AS VARCHAR) + '.' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  Address ORDER BY Address) + 1   AS VARCHAR),3) CompanyID
FROM [dbo].[TblTestNum]
```

Change the `CAST(Address AS VARCHAR)` to `100000` if you want all rows in 100000.